# Four times they anagram

Tags: word, wordplay, anagram

Four times they anagram
Once to help in judgement
Twice in the name of a book
Third could describe part of you
And last, an event with a hook

Hint

> In no particular order, four hints for four words: chopper, second, durbar, midfielder

Comment: Hey, how about a hint? :)

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie done!

Comment: I had an answer before but on @Stiv's request I have deleted it. I would undelete it for a while if someone wants a clear context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have one potential set (reaching), although I can't match one of the words. The words are

> replay - helps with judgement, e.g. VAR, associated with the word "second"

> parley - event with a hook (not sure why), associated with durbar?

> player - in the title "Ready Player One", associated with midfielder

> pearly - pearly whites, associated with chopper?

Comment: Your answers are too close to be a coincidence so I think you're nearly there! Perhaps a basketball player takes a hook shot?

Comment: You've got the four words. Though the matches with the lines in the riddle are a little mixed up.. if you reconsider them (hopefully) it will seem less far reaching

Comment: Honestly I am a bit lost so I hope someone else can assist.

Comment: @user110503 I'll say that you've correctly identified one word with both its line and hint and three words with their hint but not their line

Comment: @DanielC just one word? I am surprised. The ones I am most confident are crneyl sbe crneyl juvgr grrgu naq ercynl sbe obbx gvgyr

Comment: @user110503 crneyl jnf lbhe pbeerpg jbex. V'yy nqzvg gung gur obbx gvgyr pyhr jnf yvxryl gbb inthr. Gur nafjre whfg pnzr gb zvaq nf V jnf jevgvat gur pyhr. Vg vf vf abg gur bayl jbeq va gur gvgyr, juvpu V jnf gelvat gb pbairl jvgu "va gur anzr" vafgrnq bs "nf gur anzr"

Comment: @DanielC well I edited them, although I am not sure still how one word matches. It is only process of elimination.

Comment: rot 13(

Guveq pbhyq qrfpevor n cneg bs lbh
Crneyl(Grrgu ner crneyl juvgr)
Ynfg rirag jvgu gur ubbx
Cneyrl zrnaf fvtavat bs nezvfgvpr naq ubbx hc nyfb zrnaf gb wbva va n ebznagvp eryngvbafuvc
Zvqsvryqre nyfb eryngrf gb cbfvgvba bs cynlre va fbppre
Crneyl Grrgu pubc fbzrguvat(V thrff pubc naq grne ner vzcylvat fnzr guvat ol jbeqcynl gnt.)
Ercynl jvgu frpbaq nf cbvagrq bhg va cerivbhf nafjre
Cneyrl jvgu qheone nf qheone zrnaf pbheg va uvaqv naq nyy xvatqbzf unir pbheg.

Comment: This is correct! rot13(Crneyl > grrgu > "pubccre[f]". [ivqrb] ercynl > urycf va whqtrzrag > frpbaq [ivrjvat]. Cynlre > va gvgyr "Ernql Cynlre Bar" > zvqsvryqre cbfvgvba va fcbegf. Cneyrl jnf fgergpurq, ohg vg jnf zrnag gb ersre gb na rirag jvgu n ubbx[rq] crefba, vr, cvengr, n ersrerapr gb Cvengrf bs gur Pnevoorna. Vg vf fbzrjung bs n flabalz sbe qheone)